# How to construct a marshmallow Schema for a dictionary whose values are lists holding a single value of different types?

Tags: python, marshmallow

I have a json object that looks like this:

```py
 dic = {
     "_id": "3cef538d-0199-477e-bbf7-2a0d26d92724",
     "sID": "44155700-8476-4473-a636-685d6df021c5",
     "tID": "c48ac367-8583-43d6-959e-90d25ba1887c",
     "Type": "ParamData",
     "Param": {

         "SRT": [1589196207.91999],
         "BFW": [False],
         "INS": ["Matrix-M"],
         "LWN": [15798],
         "AN2": [0],
         "CRR": [0],
         "DUR": [4.97799682617188],
         "SRN": ["336"],
         "PKA": [-20704],
         "SSP": [True],
         "ABP": [32993],
         "AN1": [0.221665252948623],
         "PRL": [7278],
         "VSN": ["2.240 Nov 16 2011"]}
}
```

There are more key:value pairs, but this is enough to get the point that inside the single-valued lists objects are of different types. I'm constructing a Marshmallow Schema and I have the following:

```
class PQMetaSchema(Schema):
    _id = fields.Str()
    spec_igID = fields.Str(data_key='Spec_IG')
    
    paramID = fields.Str()
    fields.B
    
    Type = fields.Str(attribute='MetaData')
    Properties = fields.Dict(keys=fields.Str(), values=fields.List())
```

However, the fields.List() object in the values argument of fields.Dict()  ('Properties') requires that I pass a 'cls_or_instance', but I'm stuck since I can't pass it a list of field types nor a single type since the types vary.

Anyone care to chime in? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a several options to implement the behavior you are looking for by using [Marshmallows Custom Fields](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_fields.html) (which are quite powerful).

The easiest implement I could think of to implement a generic field in your case is using a MethodField. Note that this would not give you any kind of validation but also accepts other inputs than lists. Serialization/Deserialization therefor could throw errors.

But the get and load functions can easily be extended or you could add a validation function.

```
from marshmallow import fields, Schema


class PQMetaSchema(Schema):

    Properties = fields.Method("get_properties", deserialize="load_properties", data_key="Param")

    def get_properties(self, obj):
        return obj["Properties"]

    def load_properties(self, value):
        return dict(value)

dic = {
    "Param": {
        "SRT": [1589196207.91999],
        "BFW": [False],
        "INS": ["Matrix-M"],
        "LWN": [15798],
        "AN2": [0],
        "CRR": [0],
        "DUR": [4.97799682617188],
        "SRN": ["336"],
        "PKA": [-20704],
        "SSP": [True],
        "ABP": [32993],
        "AN1": [0.221665252948623],
        "PRL": [7278],
        "VSN": ["2.240 Nov 16 2011"]}
}

meta_schema_dict = PQMetaSchema().load(dic)
print(meta_schema_dict)
print(PQMetaSchema().dump(meta_schema_dict))
```

Comment: Sweet answer! I'm definitely gonna steal this and tell my boss I came up with all on my own. Thanx!

Comment: At least he's honest about it.